# I would like the awarded gems (high score) to represent one gem per every ten points scored

Tags: objective-c, integer, game-engine, linear-algebra, points

This must be very simple compared to the rest of my work.

Essential I have a point system where you have a score from the gameplay and then you have a score as the Gems. Say you scored 50 points during a round. I want the Gems to be 1 point for every 10 points scored during each round, so in this case the Gems would be 5 points.

Then I am having trouble figuring out how to add the new points to the Gems rather than replacing them like a high score would. For example, after receiving the 5 gems (stated above) I play another round and score 80 points, which equals 8 gems. Now I have 13 gems (5+8) rather than just 8 because its the new high amount.

Thank you for the help!

```
-(void)incrementPoints {
  if (!gameOverGame) {
    score++;
    [self runAction:scoreSound];
    SKLabelNode *scoreNode = (SKLabelNode *)[self childNodeWithName:kPointsName];
    NSString *scoreString;
    scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
    scoreNode.text = scoreString;

-(void)deleteScores{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:kScoreboardRupeeNodeName usingBlock:^(SKNode *node,BOOL *stop){
    [node removeFromParent];
 }];


if(score == A*10){
  highscore = A;
    [[AppUserDefaults sharedAppUserDefaults]setHihgscore:(int)score + highscore];
    ViewController * viewController = (ViewController *) self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [viewController submitToLeaderboard:(int)score];
  }

scoreboardNode = [gameObjects scoreboardWithScore:(int)score andHighscore:(int)highscore];
   [self addChild:scoreboardNode];
   [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:kPointsName usingBlock:^(SKNode *node,BOOL *stop){
   [node removeFromParent];
 }];
   [self die];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep track of the score as points and if 1 gem == 10 points, then that's just a *presentation issue*; i.e. rather than displaying 85 points as "85" you draw 8 gems.  i.e.

```
NSInteger numberOfGemsToDraw = self.pointsScored / 10;
```

Note that `self.pointsScored` would be saved using `NSUserDefaults` and within Game Center.  It's the only score-related data you care about.

Also note that any remaining points (i.e. `self.pointsScored % 10`) could be used to draw semi-complete gems, so the user has an idea of how close they are to their next complete gem.

**tl;dr** Store points and display gems.